# Destroy particle system when initalised programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game with a player and an enemy.

I also have a particle system for when the player dies, like an explosion.
I have made this particle system a prefab so I can use it multiple times per level as someone might die a lot.

So in my enemy.cs script, attached to my enemy, I have:

```
public GameObject deathParticle;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.name == "Player" && !player.dead){
            player.dead = true;
            Instantiate(deathParticle, player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation);
            player.animator.SetTrigger("Death");
        }
    }
```

So this plays my particle system when the player gets killed by an enemy. Now on my player script, I have this. This specific function gets played after the death animation:

```
public void RespawnPlayer()
{
    Rigidbody2D playerBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    playerBody.transform.position = spawnLocation.transform.position;
    dead = false;
    animator.Play("Idle");

    Enemy enemy = FindObjectOfType<Enemy>();
    Destroy(enemy.deathParticle);
}
```

This respawns the player like normal but in my project each time I die I have a death (clone) object which I don't want. The last 2 lines are meant to delete this but it doesn't.

I have also tried this which didn't work:

```
Enemy enemy = FindObjectOfType<Enemy>();
ParticleSystem deathParticles = enemy.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
Destroy(deathParticles);
```

Comment: Instead of destroying the enemy particle when the player dies, could you not destroy the original particle after a certain amount of time?: `GameObject newParticle = Instantiate(deathParticle, player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
Destroy(newParticle, 5f); // Destroy the particle after 5 seconds`

Comment: why is the death anim in the enemy object if it is meant for the player? Doing `FindObjectOfType` is expensive and wouldn't be necessary if the player had the prefab already.

Comment: @Tom thanks tom, this works fine. Basil, im not sure i probably should do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to `Instantiate` and `Destroy` the death particle, that will create a lot of overhead, you can simply replay it when you want it to start and stop it, when you dont need it

```
 ParticleSystem deathParticleSystem;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            #rest of the code
            deathParticleSystem.time = 0;
            deathParticleSystem.Play();

        }
    public void RespawnPlayer()
    {
        //rest of the code
        deathParticleSystem.Stop(true, ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmittingAndClear);
    }
```

or you can `enable` and `disable` the `gameObject` associated with your particle prefab

```
  public GameObject deathParticlePrefab;

        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
            {
                #rest of the code
                deathParticlePrefab.SetActive(true);

            }
        public void RespawnPlayer()
        {
            //rest of the code
            deathParticlePrefab.SetActive(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a new script and assign it to the prefab that destroys it after a certain amount of time:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class destroyOverTime : MonoBehaviour {

   public float lifeTime;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {

   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {
       lifeTime -= Time.deltaTime;

       if(lifeTime <= 0f)
       {
           Destroy(gameObject);
       }
   }
}
```

So in this case you would assign this to your deathParticle. This script is useful in a multitude of scenarios if you're instantiating objects so that you don't have a load of unnecessary objects.

Comment: Thanks. i think an eaiser way if i was to make a new script would just do particle.isPlaying but id in the end i just added a 0.7 second timer to the player script

Comment: @RachelDockter I think that would destroy the particles before the animation had even played

Comment: @RachelDockter sorry I think I may be unclear on the question, is the problem that the particles keep playing and are just there on the screen even after the player has died, or is it simply that there's loads of clone objects in your hierarchy

Comment: it doesnt loop, visually it works fine but it just made lots of clone objects. But your way fixed that